# How to skip hostname verification with Sails.js in SSL mode?

Tags: ssl, sails.js, hostname

I have a Sails.js Application enabled with SSL mode with key,cert,ca information provided in local.js.
I am able to start the server and able to communicate using certificates successfully.

By default hostname provided in the request is verified against the hostname matching the server certificate CN.

For example if server certificate CN is example.net and curl request is made with proper certificates and hostname is provided as example.net(like curl --cacert path_to_cacert --cert path_to_client_cert --key path_to_client_key https://example.net:port_number/) the communication is success and expected response is received.

If the server has DNS FQDN different from server certificate CN then curl command with DNS FQDN fails with error "**subjectAltName does not match SERVER_CN**"

Example: curl --cacert path_to_cacert --cert path_to_client_cert --key path_to_client_key https://newexample.org:port_number/
(newexample.org in this case resolves to same server to which example.net is configured)

I would like to know if there is a way to skip this hostname verification by default?
For example, I should be able to get expected response with hostname other than example.net also in above case.

I have tried adding "checkServerIdentity:false" in ssl config to see hostname verification is skipped.But that didn't help.

please let me know if we have a way to skip hostname verification in sails.js similar to hostnameVerifier in Java

Comment: Whatever your problem is, skipping hostname verification is NOT the solution. It basically means TLS is useless and you would as well just revert to plaintext. Instead generate or make someone generate the proper certificates.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly and if both domains are under your control, consider implementing Nginx as a reverse proxy then handle SSL for the domains via separate virtual hosts within your Nginx configuration.